# Cpan module Installation Error

Tags: perl

I am trying to install cpan Module. But the following error occurs

please provide solution for this

```
cpan[3]> install xml::xpath
Going to read '/Users/user/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Sun, 07 Apr 2013 09:53:02 GMT
Warning: Cannot install xml::xpath, don't know what it is.
Try the command

    i /xml::xpath/

to find objects with matching identifiers.

cpan[4]> i/xml::xpath/
Catching error: "Can't locate object method \"xpath/\" via package \"i/xml\" (perhaps you forgot to load \"i/xml\"?) at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/CPAN.pm line 375, <FIN> line 4.\cJ" at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/CPAN.pm line 391
    CPAN::shell() called at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/App/Cpan.pm line 295
    App::Cpan::_process_options('App::Cpan') called at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/App/Cpan.pm line 364
    App::Cpan::run('App::Cpan') called at /usr/bin/cpan5.12 line 12

cpan[5]>
```

Comment: Better yet, on the command line: `cpan XML::XPath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is *not* an installation error. You seem to have forgotten a space between `i` and the regex.

To search for modules, I recommend the [MetaCPAN site](https://metacpan.org/search?q=XML%3A%3AXPath).

Perl modules are case-sensitive. The correct name of the module is `XML::XPath`.

---

The cpan module seems to do a bit of meta-programming, and you tricked it into an error:

The first non-space string of your command is treated as a method name, so

```
cpan[n]> foo
```

would do

```
my $method = "foo";
$shell->$method; # like $shell->foo
```

However, you can call methods from other packages by using the fully qualified name for the method. A common occurrence is the `SUPER` pseudo-package:

```
MyClass->SUPER::new(@args);
```

Just because you can't declare packages and subs containing special characters doesn't mean that it is impossible to use them. So the fully qualified method name `i/xml::xpath/` is separated into a package name `i/xml` and a sub name `xpath/`.

It would be impossible to use such names in regular Perl code, but because the trick of using a variable as a method name, the parser is circumvented.

Comment: thanks for reply amon .I have installed Xpath module,its working